# Correlation ID error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am on my first experience in SharePoint Server installation.
I am getting `correlation ID: 8399d06f-ccc1-41a7-8221-529be9f22b3e` error when I am trying to add users and groups to my site.
Can anyone know what I missed during the installation?

Comment: no body can tell u from here...you need to provide more details about the issue, check the uls logs for that correlation ID and share here, also what is infrastruture etc

Answer (score 1):

For Correlation ID error, open your SharePoint Management Shell as administrator and run following command

```
Merge-SPLogFile –Path "c:\MergedLogs.log" –Correlation 8399d06f-ccc1-41a7-8221-529be9f22b3e
```

Above command will write error details in `MergedLogs.log` file under `c:` drive.

You can find your error details by opening this file but it is very hard to get the error from this file. Use [ULS viewer](https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) to open this file.

[image]